# Unable to link css to html

Tags: html, css

I wanted to add some css to my html, but whenever I tried to use external css, the style is never applied. When I use inline or internal css everything works as intended, and I can't find what went wrong.

Here I am using external css for my first div and inline css for my second div. The css applied to the two divs are basically the same. The css for the first div doesn't work but it does on the second so the problem isn't with the code, it with linking to the css file, but I should be doing the link tag right. The two files are definitely in the same folder.

```css
.q {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Search</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />

</head>

<body>

  <form action="https://google.com/search">
    <div class="q">
      <input type="text" name="q">
    </div>
    <div class="button" style="position:absolute; left:50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 90%);">
      <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
    </div>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use the Network tab of your browser's developer tools to debug this. Look for the request for index.css. Check that the server is responding with the correct data, content-type, and HTTP status code. Also check for errors using the Console tab.

Comment: is index.css file is located on the same folder where your .html file is placed? As per your code, html and css file should be in same folder.

Comment: href="./index.css" try with this?

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus — Why? That means exactly the same as what the OP has already, just expressed in 2 extra bytes.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of this project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been resolved. When I was trying to debug though the Network tab of my browser's developer tool, VScode suddenly prompted me saying I have two existing versions of the same file index.css and asking if I wanted to overwrite them. After overwriting the problem has been resolved. However, I am not certain if debugging though the Network tab of my browser's developer tool was what triggered VScode to identify the mixups in the directory, and if there are other methods to cause VScode to notice the problem or fix it personally.

Answer (score -2):

Look at the browser console. If it's returning `404` or something.

I tried your code on my PC and it works fine.

[image]

Comment: It runs fine but I wanted both my texts to be in the middle of the page.

Comment: The css is applied on the html when you run it?

Comment: @SunRay CSS already applied and both are already centered.